# Telegram bot error : Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Need help to find out what is wrong with a code. Task - it's a part of a test code where i try to send youtube video in bot chat to watch it in streaming mode. Sorry for mistakes and so on, i'm beginner.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import config
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["url","video"])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Video':
        bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HodO2eBEz_8", supports_streaming=True)
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```